# Huge performance difference between two similar SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two SQL queries that provides the same output.
My first intuition was to use this:

```
SELECT * FROM performance_dev.report_golden_results 
where id IN (SELECT max(id) as 'id' from  performance_dev.report_golden_results 
group by platform_id, release_id, configuration_id)
```

Now, this took something like 70 secs to complete!

Searching for another solution I tried something similar:

```
SELECT * FROM performance_dev.report_golden_results e 
join (SELECT max(id) as 'id' 
from performance_dev.report_golden_results 
group by platform_id, release_id, configuration_id) s 
ON s.id = e.id;
```

Surprisingly, this took 0.05 secs to complete!!!

how come these two are so different?

thanks!

Comment: `MySQL can have very poor performance with `in`.  This is why it is usually better to write such queries using an explicit `join`.

Comment: From what I remember, MySql can't optimise subqueries properly but your second query uses a join instead. You'll need to check the execution plan to properly see what it's doing though

Comment: Take a look at the `EXPLAIN` output for the two queries.

Comment: why didn't you try `where id =` instead of `where id IN` in the first query, as the subquery returns a scalar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing which Might Cause the Time Lag is that MySQL uses 'semi-join' strategy for Subqueries.The Semi Join includes Following Steps :

> If a subquery meets the preceding criteria, MySQL converts it to a
>   semi-join and makes a cost-based choice from these strategies:
>
> Convert the subquery to a join, or use table pullout and run the query
>   as an inner join between subquery tables and outer tables. Table
>   pullout pulls a table out from the subquery to the outer query.
>
> Duplicate Weedout: Run the semi-join as if it was a join and remove
>   duplicate records using a temporary table.
>
> FirstMatch: When scanning the inner tables for row combinations and
>   there are multiple instances of a given value group, choose one rather
>   than returning them all. This "shortcuts" scanning and eliminates
>   production of unnecessary rows.
>
> LooseScan: Scan a subquery table using an index that enables a single
>   value to be chosen from each subquery's value group.
>
> Materialize the subquery into a temporary table with an index and use
>   the temporary table to perform a join. The index is used to remove
>   duplicates. The index might also be used later for lookups when
>   joining the temporary table with the outer tables; if not, the table
>   is scanned.

But giving an explicit join reduces these efforts which might be the Reason.

I hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not consider the first query as subject for semi-join optimization (MySQL converts semi joins to classic joins with some kind of optimization: first match, duplicate weedout ...)
Thus a full scan will be made on the first table and the subquery will be evaluated for each row generated by the outer select: hence the bad performances.

The second one is a classic join, what will happen in this case that MySQL will compute the result of derived query and then matches only values from this query with values from first query satisfying the condition, hence no full scan is needed on the first table (I assumed here that id is an indexed column).

The question right now is why MySQL does not consider the first query as subject to semi-join optimization: the answer is documented in MySQL https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/semijoins.html

```
In MySQL, a subquery must satisfy these criteria to be handled as a semijoin:

It must be an IN (or =ANY) subquery that appears at the top level of the WHERE or ON clause, possibly as a term in an AND expression. For example:

SELECT ...
FROM ot1, ...
WHERE (oe1, ...) IN (SELECT ie1, ... FROM it1, ... WHERE ...);
Here, ot_i and it_i represent tables in the outer and inner parts of the query, and oe_i and ie_i represent expressions that refer to columns in the outer and inner tables.

It must be a single SELECT without UNION constructs.

It must not contain a GROUP BY or HAVING clause.

It must not be implicitly grouped (it must contain no aggregate functions).

It must not have ORDER BY with LIMIT.

The STRAIGHT_JOIN modifier must not be present.

The number of outer and inner tables together must be less than the maximum number of tables permitted in a join.
```

Your subquery use GROUP BY hence semi-join optimization was not applied.